# How to get right row height in Qt for QTableView object?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview

From this screenshot you can see a lot of space inside the rows:

[image]

I've used these functions to get resizing:

```
resizeRowsToContents();
resizeColumnsToContents();
```

How can I get a better fit for cells/rows sizes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try these:

```
verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(int size)
horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(int size)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
void QHeaderView::setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: That works well for columns, but doesn't seem to work with rows.

Comment: For me this does appear to work for rows... hmmm (PyQt5)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in Qt when you call resizeRowsToContents on the tableView of an empty table with a hidden verticalHeader, it does not accurately resize the rows. And considering that tables often start empty, this is a troublesome problem indeed. Fortunately I found a workaround on a [qtcentre thread](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20720-Minimise-row-height-in-Tables), as follows:

**If table/model is *not* empty, use:**

```
        tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
        const int rowHeight = tableView->verticalHeader()->sectionSize(0);
        tableView->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(rowHeight);
```

**Otherwise, here is a workaround:**

```
        // workaround for Qt empty table auto-row-sizing problem
        const int rowHeight = tableView->verticalHeader()->minimumSectionSize();
        tableView->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(rowHeight);
```

Comment: Hmmm... this seems to set every row to the same height.

Comment: @mikerodent for an empty table, yes it does. in my case I wanted all the rows to be the same height though, so it was fine.

Comment: My tables aren't empty and the rows are different heights. In my system this imposes the same height for each row. There is therefore no point in calling resizeRowsToContents before setDefaultSectionSize.

Comment: @mikerodent yes, there is an effect. resizeRowsToContents affects the existing rows with contents. if you allow word wrap for example, some could end up double height. setDefaultSectionSize affects the future rows which have not yet been inserted.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm using Qt 4.7 and this worked for me on `QTableView`:**

```
tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so do many others it seems:

http://www.qtforum.org/article/13421/qtableview-how-to-make-rows-size-smaller.html

My quick hack job for a simple table with a few rows only (assume all rows have same text height and this probably only works for some fonts maybe only on Windo):

```
int rowHeight = ui.tableView_Available->rowHeight(0) *1/2;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
  ui.tableView_Available->verticalHeader()->resizeSection(i, rowHeight);
```

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
QTimer::singleShot(1, ui->tableView, SLOT(resizeRowsToContents()));
```